# How do you specify multiple values for the inputTensorName key in INPUTMETADATA spec in Vertex Explainable AI for a Functional API model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-cloud-ai-platform-pipelines, xai

I want to add explanation to my model running in Vertex AI using the Vertex AI SDK.I get a silent error when running the batch prediction using ModelBatchPredictOp, where the ModelBatchPredictOp node runs infinitely.Here is my ModelBatchPredictOp definition;

```py
ModelBatchPredictOp(
    project=project_id,
    job_display_name="tensorflow-ex-batch-prediction-job",
    location=project_location,
    model=champion_model.outputs["model"],
    instances_format="csv",
    predictions_format="jsonl",
    gcs_source_uris=gcs_source_uris,
    gcs_destination_output_uri_prefix=gcs_destination_output_uri_prefix,
    machine_type=batch_prediction_machine_type,
    starting_replica_count=batch_prediction_min_replicas,
    max_replica_count=batch_prediction_max_replicas,
    generate_explanation=True,
)
```

I have narrowed down the issue to inputTensorName key in the INPUTMETADATA spec.The 'inputTensorName' key in the INPUTMETADATA spec takes in a string for it's value([INPUTMETADATA spec](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/ExplanationSpec#InputMetadata)). In my case I have a tensorflow model defined using the functional API meaning it has multiple inputs, as shown below;

```py
# numeric/categorical features in Chicago trips dataset to be preprocessed
NUM_COLS = ["dayofweek", "hourofday", "trip_distance", "trip_miles", "trip_seconds"]
ORD_COLS = ["company"]
OHE_COLS = ["payment_type"]

def build_and_compile_model(dataset: Dataset, model_params: dict) -> Model:
        """Build and compile model.

        Args:
            dataset (Dataset): training dataset
            model_params (dict): model parameters

        Returns:
            model (Model): built and compiled model
        """

        # create inputs (scalars with shape `()`)
        num_ins = {
            name: Input(shape=(), name=name, dtype=tf.float32) for name in NUM_COLS
        }
        ord_ins = {
            name: Input(shape=(), name=name, dtype=tf.string) for name in ORD_COLS
        }
        cat_ins = {
            name: Input(shape=(), name=name, dtype=tf.string) for name in OHE_COLS
        }

        # join all inputs and expand by 1 dimension. NOTE: this is useful when passing
        # in scalar inputs to a model in Vertex AI batch predictions or endpoints e.g.
        # `{"instances": {"input1": 1.0, "input2": "str"}}` instead of
        # `{"instances": {"input1": [1.0], "input2": ["str"]}`
        all_ins = {**num_ins, **ord_ins, **cat_ins}
        exp_ins = {n: tf.expand_dims(i, axis=-1) for n, i in all_ins.items()}

        # preprocess expanded inputs
        num_encoded = [normalization(n, dataset)(exp_ins[n]) for n in NUM_COLS]
        ord_encoded = [str_lookup(n, dataset, "int")(exp_ins[n]) for n in ORD_COLS]
        ohe_encoded = [str_lookup(n, dataset, "one_hot")(exp_ins[n]) for n in OHE_COLS]

        # ensure ordinal encoded layers is of type float32 (like the other layers)
        ord_encoded = [tf.cast(x, tf.float32) for x in ord_encoded]

        # concat encoded inputs and add dense layers including output layer
        x = num_encoded + ord_encoded + ohe_encoded
        x = Concatenate()(x)
        for units, activation in model_params["hidden_units"]:
            x = Dense(units, activation=activation)(x)
        x = Dense(1, name="output", activation="linear")(x)

        model = Model(inputs=all_ins, outputs=x, name="nn_model")
        model.summary()

        logging.info(f"Use optimizer {model_params['optimizer']}")
        optimizer = optimizers.get(model_params["optimizer"])
        optimizer.learning_rate = model_params["learning_rate"]

        model.compile(
            loss=model_params["loss_fn"],
            optimizer=optimizer,
            metrics=model_params["metrics"],
        )

        return model
```

As a consequence when getting the input layer, using;

```py
serving_input = list(
        loaded_model.signatures["serving_default"].structured_input_signature[1].keys()
    )[0]
  
INPUT_METADATA = {
   "input_tensor_name": serving_input,
   "encoding": "BAG_OF_FEATURES",
   "modality": "numeric",
   "index_feature_mapping": cols,
}
```

I only get one Input layer corresponding to one of the input tensors (cols) in either NUM_COLS, ORD_COLS or OHE_COLS. This causes an infinite run when running the ModelBatchPredictOp in the prediction pipeline as only the name to one input tensor is passed as the value to the inputTensorName. Running

```py
list(model.signatures["serving_default"].structured_input_signature[1].keys())
```

returns the a list of all the input layers corresponding to the input tensor names (cols) defined in NUM_COLS, ORD_COLS and OHE_COLS.

How do I specify the value of inputTensorName in order to capture all the input layers? Or is there a work around to assign multiple input tensor names to inputTensorName?